# Python Spotify OAuth Flow

Tags: python, http, python-requests, spotify, http-redirect

So I'm trying to build an authorization flow with with the Spotify Web API. 
So the first call is just a GET against a URL and I'm passing the credentials and other stuff necessary to authorize my app as parameters. 
After that the user is prompted to authorize my app then is redirected to a callback URL.

The url I'm redirected to contains some response data as parameters and I need that data to then POST against the API and retrieve the token.

How do I retrieve the response URL and access those parameters? Sorry for the naive question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a webserver listening at the callback URL?

Comment: Hmmm. Well I'm not sure what do you mean with "webserver listening". The callback url is my personal website domain linked to my own server. Is there a way to setup my server to capture that data so I can retrieve it?

Comment: Yes so what's probably happening is that the API service is POST-ing the information back to your callback URL. What service are you trying to authenticate with?

Comment: Spotify. I'm trying to build the authorization flow as described here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/
Do you see another way to make this easier? I'm just avoiding the available API wrappers because the documentation is horrible.

Comment: Right so step 3 will require you to have a server listening to get the "code" portion in able to make requests on behalf of a user. This is the standard OAuth workflow outlined here: http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html

I'll update my answer to work for spotify

Comment: Awesome man!! I would truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with just requests.

I would check out a package like: https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth, OAuthException


SPOTIFY_APP_ID = 'REGULAR_CODE'
SPOTIFY_APP_SECRET = 'SECRET_CODE'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'
oauth = OAuth(app)

spotify = oauth.remote_app(
    'spotify',
    consumer_key=SPOTIFY_APP_ID,
    consumer_secret=SPOTIFY_APP_SECRET,
    # Change the scope to match whatever it us you need
    # list of scopes can be found in the url below
    # https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/
    request_token_params={'scope': 'user-read-email'},
    base_url='https://accounts.spotify.com',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_url='/api/token',
    authorize_url='https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    callback = url_for(
        'spotify_authorized',
        next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None,
        _external=True
    )
    return spotify.authorize(callback=callback)


@app.route('/login/authorized')
def spotify_authorized():
    resp = spotify.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason={0} error={1}'.format(
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    if isinstance(resp, OAuthException):
        return 'Access denied: {0}'.format(resp.message)

    session['oauth_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    me = spotify.get('/me')
    return 'Logged in as id={0} name={1} redirect={2}'.format(
        me.data['id'],
        me.data['name'],
        request.args.get('next')
    )


@spotify.tokengetter
def get_spotify_oauth_token():
    return session.get('oauth_token')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Hey @ranman thanks for the solution. I was implementing it but I got this error in flask: "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded". 

So I'm kind of stucked with that exception. I was expecting to see a rendered page telling me "Logged in as id**** name***** etc..." so I don't know if I'm effectively getting the token. I'm also not so sure how I can pass that token to my other script. Any help would be treasured. Greetings.

Comment: I know it's been a few years, but maybe it will be helpful for someone else. Instead of `me = spotify.get('/me')` should be `me = spotify.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me')`. And instead of `me.data['name']` should be `me.data['display_name']`

Answer (score 0):

You can GET a JSON response with all parameters that you need, example.

You login to a www.example.com/login/

GET http://www.example.com/login/ (With header and Basic access authentication or the auth process that you use) and this URL return a JSON Response with the data:

```
{
  'status': 'OK',
  'token': {
    'public_token': 'blabla',
    'private_token': 'blabla'},
  'created_at': '2014-11-03'
}
```

That data you can save in database for future use.